# Regex looking for two patterns at a time in single foreach loop

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file with content something like this:

```
+++++ jcguox 4/2/2011 6:19:47 AM

text here

+++++ viveksix 8/24/2012 4:09:17 AM

text again

+++++ viveksix 8/25/2012 11:01:30 AM

----- Vivek Singh 08/25/2012 11:28:12 PM

adding text

+++++ viveksix 8/25/2012 11:02:52 AM

adding more
```

I want to select all patterns of type `+++++name date time` in `arraylist` but with the condition that:

- If `-----name date time appears` immediately after `+++++name date time` then this `+++++name date time` should not get added to `arraylist`.
- Only if text appears after `+++++name date time` then this `+++++name date time` should get added to `arraylist`.

Right now I'm able to parse both patterns `+++++name date time` and `-----name date time` using `Regex.matches`.

Question is how to apply in loop something like:

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(textfile,@"+++++name date time" + @"-----name date time")
{
    if(after +++++name date time text is there)
        arraylist.Add("+++++name date time");
    else if(after +++++name date time -----name date time is there)
        //do not add in arraylist;
}



output for above case is : 

+++++ jcguox 4/2/2011 6:19:47 AM
+++++ viveksix 8/24/2012 4:09:17 AM
+++++ viveksix 8/25/2012 11:02:52 AM
```

Comment: immediately after means "the next line"?

Comment: why do you want to do that with a regex, rather than a for loop?

Comment: yes .. there could be spaces although

Comment: Regex helps me to select both the patterns.. i want to check if two patterns appear together(just next to each other) then just donot add the pattern(+++++name date time) in arraylist else add(+++++name date time)

Comment: Are you still using c#1 or 2?  If not, why are you still using ArrayList?  You should be using a strongly typed collection instead, such as List<T>

Comment: how can i combine the two patterns together in single loop of foreach(Match m in Regex.matches(string,pattern 1 + pattern 2) and applying my if/else condition then. i'm seperately using @"[+]{5}.* \d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M" (for +++++name date time) @"[-]{5}.* \d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M"(for -----name date time)

Answer (score 0):

check this out...

```
Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\++ (?<author>\w+) (?<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) (?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (?:AM|PM))(?!\r\n\r\n-+)")
```

Comment: it uses negative lookahead -- maybe you have to change your line-endings (at the end of the regex) to match the file-line-endings (here it's \r\n, maybe it's only \n)

Comment: i have this two readymade patterns.. can you just help me in this .. @"[+]{5}.* \d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M" (for +++++name date time)                           @"[-]{5}.* \d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M"(for -----name date time)

Comment: where's your point?
my regex ignores the COUNT of trailing "+" and "-" (because it sould be totally ignorably), and makes human-readable capture groups, which you can address nicely in code?!

maybe you should share the part of your c#-implementation, so that we can improve that whole thing

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string input = @" i have a text file with content something like this:

     +++++ jcguox 4/2/2011 6:19:47 AM

    text here

    +++++ viveksix 8/24/2012 4:09:17 AM

    text again


    +++++ viveksix 8/25/2012 11:01:30 AM

    ----- Vivek Singh 08/25/2012 11:28:12 PM

    adding text


    +++++ viveksix 8/25/2012 11:02:52 AM

    adding more";

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, @"\++ (?<author>\w+) (?<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) (?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (?:AM|PM))(?!\r\n\r\n-+)");
        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            string st = m.NextMatch().ToString();
            if (Regex.Match(st, @"\++ (?<author>\w+) (?<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) (?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (?:AM|PM))(?!\r\n\r\n-+)").Length > 0)
            {
                al.Add(st);
            }

        }
```